# SQL Server Query not executing as expected PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sql-server-2012, sqlsrv

I got stuck at while implementing jquery autocomplete with ajax the same fuction works for another table but in 2 tables(sales_man, Cashcustomer) its returing empty array but the fist table(customerMaster) it works fine and listing every cust as its request.
My code

**myApp.js**

```
$('#custName').autocomplete({ 
      minLength: 1,
      autoFocus:true,
      source: function( request, response ) {

          $.ajax({
              url: "/test/ajax/ajaxOpRespond.php",
              data: {action:'Get_CashCust_Code', code:request.term},
              dataType:'JSON',
              type: "POST",
              success: function( data ) {
                var result = [];

                if(data.length > 0){
                  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){  

                  result[i] = { "value" :data[i].CUST.CUST_NAME+" ("+data[i].CUST.TELE_NO+")", 
                 "custName":data[i].CUST.CUST_NAME,
                 "custtel1":data[i].CUST.TELE_NO,


                };
                  }
                }      
                else{
                  alert("jesha mesha");
                  $('#custType').val("new");
                }                                     
                  response(result);
              },
              error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){                    
               alert("fail"+errorThrown);
              var result = [];
              response( result );
          }
          });
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#custName").val(ui.item.custName);

        $('#custTel1').val(ui.item.custtel1);$('#custTel1').attr("readonly","true");
        $('#custType').val("old");



          return false;
       }
    });
```

**ajaxController.php**

```
case 'Get_CashCust_Code':
            $code = $_POST['code'];

            $msql = "SELECT [ID]
  ,[CUST_NAME]
  ,[TELE_NO] FROM [dbo].[tbl_CashCustomer_Master] WHERE [CUST_NAME] LIKE '%{$code}%' ;";
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $msql);
            if( $stmt === false ) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                    }
            if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false || sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt ) === false) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                    }
                    $rows = array();

            while( $r = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $rows[] = array('CUST' => $r);

            }
            sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

            echo json_encode($rows);


            break;
```

[output on Server studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm8Zo.jpg)

on ajax request it just return '[]'

please help

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: that's `request.term`?

Comment: @Psi I am aware of that I will patch up all security flaws once it's finished

Comment: check your browser console for errors. Check in your browser network tab what the what the ajax request is actually returning. If that's not correct, then maybe something is wrong on the server-side. This is all basic debugging you can do for yourself.

Comment: @Forbs it's the search input value

Comment: @ADyson no errors just returning empty array

Comment: preventative programming: fix bugs as soon as you find them... you'll never find all of them again

Comment: @Psi Okay thank you

Comment: In that case, you've checked in your network tools that it sends the variable to the server correctly? You've checked it runs the query? Have you checked the SQL created is as you expect? Again, you can debug all of this. We cannot.

Comment: @ADyson i printed query with parameters and executed the same on server studio the query returns rows but ajax responds empty array

Comment: @all I have found my solution and answered my question this may help others too and thanks for all your support and advice cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of search and tries, i found my issue when i posted my question i was unaware of what was the real issue here and why it returns empty, well my actual problem was the first row is excluded from the response array when i added the same customer 2 times only one was listed on autocomplete this is because i executed and fetched the query 2 times at the same time

```
     case 'Get_CashCust_Code':
                    $code = $_POST['code'];

                    $msql = "SELECT [ID]
          ,[CUST_NAME]
          ,[TELE_NO] FROM [dbo].[tbl_CashCustomer_Master] WHERE [CUST_NAME] LIKE '%{$code}%' ;";
                    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $msql);
                    if( $stmt === false ) {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                            }
    /*sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) is fetching all rows */         
if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false || sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt ) === false)  {
                            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                            }
                            $rows = array();

     /*sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) fetching rows for the second time*/              
 while( $r = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        $rows[] = array('CUST' => $r);

                    }
                    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

                    echo json_encode($rows);


                    break;
```

By reading the solution 
[here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29060306/Missing-first-row-from-SQLsrv-fetch-array.html#a42318264) he mentioned the mechanism of execution i understood when while is executing my pointer starts from 1 instead 0

**Quoting his answer to that problem below**

> The sqlsrv_fetch_array() method retrieves a record and advances the
>   cursor by one. You're looping through your records on line 190 in your
>   while loop, but on line 21 you have this:
>
> $auditData = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC),
>
> so you have already fetched the first record. By the time you hit the
>   loop on line 190, you're already on record 2.
>
> You have a couple of options. One is to change your while loop to a
>   do/while loop:
>
> do {  ... } while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt,
>   SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
>
> You would need to change line 21 (and associated rows) to be $row =
>   ... instead of $auditData = ...
>
> Alternatively, you could reset your pointer before starting your main
>   loop. Can't remember how to do that with the SqlServer driver, but a
>   quick google should set you on the right track.

I actually tired do while and same issue that's when I changed

```
  if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false || sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt ) === false) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                    }
```

to

```
/* removed the first fetch */
     if(sqlsrv_has_rows( $stmt ) === false) {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                        }
```

and now its working fine as expected, And thanks for your help and @Psi Thanks for notifying me of the SQL injection attack